# The screen recording time is inconsistent with the actual use time in PyQt with opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pyqt5

Recently, I'm writing a code about screen recorder. Python3.5+PyQt+Opencv3.2 are used in this program.
I got a problem. When I use the program to record 10 seconds of video, the actual recorded file's video only 5 seconds, and the speed of moving looks faster (maybe 2 times faster).
I don't know why. Is there anyone can help me? Thank you very much!

The main idea of this program is that:

1. when the start button is clicked, then begin a `timer`.
2. in the function `captureScreen`, capture the screen, then write into the video file.
3. when the stop button is clicked, then stop the `timer`

The source code is put here

ui.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '.\screen_capture.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.8.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_mainDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainDialog):
        mainDialog.setObjectName("mainDialog")
        mainDialog.resize(200, 42)
        mainDialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 42))
        mainDialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 42))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(mainDialog)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.startBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(mainDialog)
        self.startBtn.setObjectName("startBtn")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.startBtn)
        self.stopBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(mainDialog)
        self.stopBtn.setObjectName("stopBtn")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.stopBtn)

        self.retranslateUi(mainDialog)
        self.startBtn.clicked.connect(mainDialog.startBtn_clicked)
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(mainDialog.stopBtn_clicked)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainDialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mainDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainDialog", "Screen Capture"))
        self.startBtn.setText(_translate("mainDialog", "开始录制"))
        self.stopBtn.setText(_translate("mainDialog", "停止录制"))
```

mainDialog.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

__author__ = '350187947@qq.com'

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from ui import *
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2

class MainDialog(QDialog,Ui_mainDialog):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainDialog,self).__init__(parent)
        # UI properties
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
        # video parameter
        self.__fps = 25.0
        self.__filename = "1stTest.avi"
        self.__codecs = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
        im = ImageGrab.grab()  # capture the screen
        frame = np.array(im)  # change the frame from Image to np array

        self.__height, self.__width, self.__depth = frame.shape  # get the shape of the frame
        print(self.__height, self.__width, self.__depth)

        self.__timer = QTimer(self)
        self.__timer.timeout.connect(self.capturing)

    def capturing(self):
        # self.__timer.setInterval(1000.0 / self.__fps)
        frame = self.captureScreen()
        self.videoWrite(self.__video,frame)


    def setFps(self, fps=25.0):
        self.__fps = fps

    def setFilename(self, filename):
        self.__filename = filename

    # 1' create a videowriter
    # 2' set timer intervel
    # 3' start timer

    def startBtn_clicked(self):
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(True)
        self.startBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.__video = cv2.VideoWriter(self.__filename, self.__codecs, self.__fps, (self.__width, self.__height), True) # Make a video writer
        self.__timer.start(1000/self.__fps)

    def stopBtn_clicked(self):
        self.__timer.stop()
        self.__video.release()
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.startBtn.setEnabled(True)

    def captureScreen(self):
        # capture the screen
        im = ImageGrab.grab()
        # change the frame from Image to nparray
        frame = np.array(im)
        # convert the color from BGR to RGB
        frame2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        return frame2

    def videoWrite(self,video,frame):
        if not type(video)==type(cv2.VideoWriter()):
            raise TypeError('video type ERROR')
        if not isinstance(frame,np.ndarray):
            raise TypeError('frame type ERROR')
        video.write(frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    main function
    '''

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainDialog = MainDialog()
    mainDialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This sounds like your source FPS is not the same as your output FPS. Maybe capturing and saving the image takes longer than the FPS (I would expect that) and QTimer won't do any calls if the system is busy... It may sound harder, but maybe you can have the callback call grab image and place it in a queue to be processed by another thread?

Comment: Thank you. If I reduce the fps, so maybe the time will be correct? And if i want to get a higher fps video, i need to do like you said? Another question, i want to write a screen recoder, and what is the best solution?

Comment: Well i think it should be with at least 2 threads, one to grab and putting it in a queue and another one writing it, but no idea in general since this probably will consume a lot of memory after a while if the thread that grabs is faster than the other one

Comment: thank you very much. i will try.